# Absolute convergance of function series

Tags: calculus, power-series

The question is for which values of $x\in \mathbb R$, the following series absolute/conditionally converge: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)}$$ I have no idea how to solev it except M-test of wirestrass but I don't know how to bound it . Forgive me if tagging the question as 'power-series' was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$u_n=\frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)}$$
so we have 
$$\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{1+x^{n+1}}\right|\to\left\{\begin{array}\\
|x| \quad\text{if}\quad -1<x<1\\
\frac{1}{2} \quad\text{if}\quad x=1\\
0 \quad\text{if}\quad -1<x \,\text{or}\, x>1
\end{array}\right.$$
so we can see by the ratio test that the series converges absolutely for all $x\neq -1$

Comment: I don't think I can use the radtio test in this question, Sorry :(

Comment: You can use the ratio test to any  series so what's the problem ?

Comment: problem is that this question is a part of an excerise about sequences of functions and serieses. Mayeb the practitioner wants a way which invloves wirestrass test...